# How can I find which row turns more than one: ORA-01427 error

Tags: sql, oracle

I got an ORA-01427 :"single-row subquery returns more than one row" error. I know what does it mean but I want to find which row turns more than one row and I wonder why the subquery run but not create new table.

Here is my query:

```
create table ana_ucret_indirim as
select v1.* , 
(select olmasi_gereken_indirim from indirimler_ana_ucretlerle_grup v2 where v2.tah_donem=v1.tah_donem and v2.abone_id= v1.abone_id and v2.bagli_tarife_id=v1.id) as olmasi_gereken_indirim
from ana_ucret_tablosuv1 v1
```

I can run this part:

```
select v1.* , 
(select olmasi_gereken_indirim from indirimler_ana_ucretlerle_grup v2 where v2.tah_donem=v1.tah_donem and v2.abone_id= v1.abone_id and v2.bagli_tarife_id=v1.id) as olmasi_gereken_indirim
from ana_ucret_tablosuv1 v1
```

But I can't create a table.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: What exactly do want to do with your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find which row turns more than one row

Starting from this correlated subquery:

```
select olmasi_gereken_indirim 
from indirimler_ana_ucretlerle_grup v2 
where v2.tah_donem=v1.tah_donem and v2.abone_id= v1.abone_id and v2.bagli_tarife_id=v1.id
```

You can get the "duplicates" in the source table with the following aggregate query;

```
select tah_donem, abone_id, bagli_tarife_id
from indirimler_ana_ucretlerle_grup v2 
group by tah_donem, abone_id, bagli_tarife_id
having count(*) > 1
```

We can also filter on dups that do exist in the base table of your query, using `exists` - those are the tuples that *do* create issues when you run your original statement:

```
select tah_donem, abone_id, bagli_tarife_id
from indirimler_ana_ucretlerle_grup v2 
where exists (
    select 1
    from ana_ucret_tablosuv1  v1
    where v2.tah_donem=v1.tah_donem and v2.abone_id= v1.abone_id and v2.bagli_tarife_id=v1.id
)
group by tah_donem, abone_id, bagli_tarife_id
having count(*) > 1
```